# How to block Digital Ocean Inc. Google Analytics Direct Traffic using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, google-analytics

**Explanation:** I have gone through my Google Analytics and noticed I am receiving direct traffic from Digital Ocean Inc. multiple times a day (around 24) as new visits 100% bounce rate and 0 second page duration. Further research shows that its just a cloud service but I also found a list of blacklisted IP's [here](https://graphiclineweb.wordpress.com/tech-notes/ip-blacklist/ip-ranges-banned/) and multiple other people reporting the same traffic.

**Question:** Since I have this range of IP's that may or may not be my problem would I be able to block these IP's from accessing my site using my .htaccess file? Is there a better method other than just filtering out the traffic using a Google analytics filter?

**IP's Listed by website for Digital Ocean Inc:** 198.211.96.0 - 198.211.127.255

Comment: Check this http://lonegoatuk.tumblr.com/post/107307494431/google-analytics-referral-spambot-list

Comment: I looked at that link already before I posted but I found this that best helped me if anyone else is interested in blocking digital ocean inc at least from google analytics.. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/srumT0q4Uow

Comment: Check out the comments in this post, there's mention of including the hostname instead of excluding everything else. https://plus.google.com/100582165749296472339/posts/fKJA9yXeXaW

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue on my recent launch... How I plan on fixing it is blocking the ISP Provider instead of IP address.

also im adding to my .htaccess

```
  #get rid of the bad bot
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DigitalOceanInc.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://go.away/
```

[image: Block Digital Ocean Web Bot...]