# Blocking a user agent with htaccess (Digital Ocean)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm looking to block a user agent (Digital Ocean) and saw this thread. For some reason, it's not working. Is it possible they changed their user agent? If so, do you know how to look up a user agent or what the new one may be?

[How to block Digital Ocean Inc. Google Analytics Direct Traffic using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955965/how-to-block-digital-ocean-inc-google-analytics-direct-traffic-using-htaccess)

```
#get rid of the bad bot
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DigitalOceanInc.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://go.away/
```

Comment: How do you know it's "not working"?

Comment: Google analytics shows unchanged direct traffic / spam from digital ocean inc.

Comment: Also tried with just DigitalOcean as the user agent.

Comment: You maybe seeing analytics spam. To check that this code is working you need to check your access log for a 302 response to such requests. The access log also shows the user agent used in the request. You also need the `L` flag on that rule if you have other directives in your file. Presumably this rule is near the top of your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} DigitalOcean [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Comment: Please include an explanation, rather than just a code dump - this is likely to be considered "low quality" by the system. Why is this an improvement on what the OP is using? Generally, with _blocking_ directives, you should not use the `NC` flag, since the user agent is usually a known, fixed entity. You also don't need the `L` flag when using `F` - the `L` flag is implied here.

Comment: I've looked at a dozen or so stackoverflow pages about using .htaccess to block user agents. None of the pages give an explanation about what the syntax means. This leaves me with little confidence that it will work.